# Reorder (collate) vector elements automatically

Tags: r

It's an easy one, but I can find a simple solution for my problem. I have several vectors look like this one: `rep(1:3, each = 3)` and I want to convert them to like `rep(1:3, times = 3)`.

So each element is repeated multiple times `c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)` and I want to reorder them to `c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Use `times` instead of `each`, `rep(1:3, times = 3)`

Comment: If you're not creating them with `rep` but still need to reorder, use a matrix transpose, `as.vector(t(matrix(x, nrow = 3)))` where `x <- rep(1:3, each = 3)`

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a matrix transpose:

```
as.vector(t(matrix(x, nrow = 3)))
# [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v1 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)

o1 <- rle(v1)
rep(o1$values, min(o1$length))

[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

This allows for unknown amount of numbers or strings but expects each value to be present in equal numbers. It only has some flexibility on what you want to do on some values occuring more than others.

Consider:

```
v2 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
o2 <- rle(v2)

rep(o2$values, min(o2$length))
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

rep(o2$values, max(o2$length))
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```